# Store infrequently changing info in Spring App

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nosql, spring-data, microservices

I am working On a Microservice (Spring boot) that require to store some static information that infrequently changes (once per quarter). The data (below) is about the company reports that looks like

```
reportId#1: "frequency"="daily","to":"some email ids"
reportId#2: "frequency"="weekly", "to":"some emailids"
```

As you can see an entry in the data is basically a Report id, and associated attributes are  frequency of reports and receiver's email id.

My question is.. What is the best place to store this information? I have some thoughts..and here are my views.

a)  NoSQL DB like MongoDB seems to be a good option.. I can create a Collection and store it there and retrieve it once during app startup. But the  I thought, whether creating a Collection just to store this static info is a good choice?

b) Redis seems to be another good option.  I can create a template for above dataset and store it there. I can query the Redis based on the reportId to retrieve the frequency and senders list.

c) Store it in a file in the classpath and load at the app startup. The downside is that, I will have to redeploy the app with new changes in file whenever this report listing changes. I believe externalizing this information to either Mongo or Redis is a better option.

d) The app is running in the AWS..so I can even store this in a file in S3 bucket.

Would like to know your views?

Answer (score 0):

Since the config will only change once a quarter, the overheard of a database is not required. You should consider Apache commons configuration. It will allow you to load config changes from files without the need for an application restart.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration///userguide/howto_reloading.html

Comment: The application I am talking about is running in a docker container..so I need to put that file somewhere in the packaged file. I am planning to keep that file outside the application installable file.